# C# Retry Policy: How to check what exception you receive as a variable?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a retry policy created for SQL Exceptions but it seems to not be retrying properly.

I am currently trying to debug and I want to create a temporary code line to test if the exception is a SQL Exception:

```
if (exception == SQLException) then bool correct = true;
```

But how would I create an exception variable?

I am currently causing the exception by using RAISERROR('test', 16, 1); in the stored procedures in the database and also creating a SQL timeout.

Just want to check if the exception I'm receiving is a SQL Exception or if it's not even registering.

Thank you

Comment: You really need to show us a [mcve]. The code you've provided is not complete and it is clearly wrong too.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want to do is [use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385174/3034273). Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi! Could you elaborate more on the tests you run? If you are using mocks you could just setup your mock to throw whatever exception you want to test, instead of creating exceptions in the SQL code

Comment: Can you please share the code where you want to check the exception?

Comment: Are you looking for `try {...} catch(Exception ex) {Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);}`?([DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch))

Comment: `then`?!? not in c#...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure enough about the context, but if you have the exception object, then try the `is` operator

```
if (ExceptionObject is SqlException ) 
{
  //run the retry logic for SqlException 
}
```

The details are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the SqlException and check for the Class and State properties:

```
if (exception is SqlException sqlException) 
{
    if(sqlException.Class == 16 && sqlException.State == 1)
    {
          
    }
}
```